# How to get field name instead of foreign id in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

In my django app, i have four model tables linked using foreign keys, the problem is, when i make a query for any model table, the fields that are linked through foreign keys are returned as id's instead of the name.

My way does not work.

My **customers models.py** file

*1st model*

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.png', upload_to='customer_photos/%Y/%m/%d/')
    data_added = models.DateField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

*2nd model*

```
class ShippingAddress(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="customer_ship_address")
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)   
    frequent_customer = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    zip_code = models.CharField(max_length=12, blank=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.customer.name
```

*3rd model - PaymentInvoice*

```
class paymentInvoice(models.Model):

    shipping_address_owner = models.ForeignKey(
        ShippingAddress, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="customer_invoice")
    product = models.ManyToManyField(
        Product, related_name='product_invoice')
    mode = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=paymentMode.choices, default=paymentMode.MPESA)
    date = models.DateField(default=datetime.now)
    invoice_id = models.CharField(
        max_length=50, unique=True, default=increment_invoice_number)
    quantity = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    status = models.CharField(
        max_length=20, choices=paymentStatus.choices, default=paymentStatus.PENDING)
    payment_made = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=2)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.shipping_address_owner.customer.name
```

My **Products models.py** file

```
class Product(models.Model):
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    available = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default_product.jpg', upload_to='product_photos')
    category = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    qty_amount = models.CharField(
        max_length=20, choices=Qty_Choices, default='250ml')
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

My **PaymentInvoice views.py** file

```
class paymentInvoiceListCreateView(ListCreateAPIView):
    """
    ListCreateAPIView executes both 'GET' and 'POST' requests. i.e listing a queryset or creating a model instance.
    """
    serializer_class = paymentInvoiceSerializer
    queryset = paymentInvoice.objects.all().order_by(
        '-date').values(shipping_address_owner__customer)
```

When i make the above query the api returns the following, where the *product* field and *shipping_address_owner* field are just id's. I need there respective names instead.

```
{
    "count": 6,
    "next": null,
    "previous": null,
    "results": [
        {
            "id": 9,
            "mode": "Mpesa",
            "date": "2020-07-27",
            "invoice_id": "INV-0006",
            "quantity": 1,
            "status": "Pending",
            "payment_made": "500.00",
            "shipping_address_owner": 9,
            "product": [
                1
            ]
        },
```

EDIT: **paymentInvoiceSerializer**

```
class paymentInvoiceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = paymentInvoice
        fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: To do this you need to modify your `paymentInvoiceSerializer`

Add serializers.MethodField for both product and shipping_address_owner that takes in an id and returns the name

Comment: I have added the **paymentInvoiceSerializer** kindly advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make some changes to your serializer.

If you just need the name and nothing more:

```
class paymentInvoiceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    product = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    shipping_address_owner = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = paymentInvoice
        fields = '__all__'
    
    def get_product(self, instance):
        names = []
        for product in instance.product.all():
            names.append(product.name)
        return names
    
    def get_shipping_address_owner(self, instance):
        return instance.shipping_address_owner.customer.name
```

You can also create different serializer for each model and pass them to their fields to get the full serialized data for them. It would be something like this:

```
ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = '__all__'
```

And then in your payment serializer:

```
class paymentInvoiceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    product = ProductSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = paymentInvoice
        fields = '__all__'
```

You can do the same for `shipping_address_owner`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this in your serializer.

```
class paymentInvoiceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    shipping_address_owner = serializers.CharField(source='shipping_address_owner.customer')
    class Meta:
        model = paymentInvoice
        fields = ['shipping_address_owner',...]
```